# Adding scores to a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to coding and I have completed Codecademy's HTML, CSS and Javascript courses, and now I am making a very simple game.

I am trying to add 5 to my variable score, but I don't know how! I can use `++score` to add 1, but I don't know how to add 5.

My simplified code for adding 1 is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Webpage</title>
<script>
var score = 0;
function add1() {
    alert("Adding +1 to your score!");
    ++score;
    alert(score);
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="add1()";> Add One </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you try score + 5?

Comment: [Try jQuery](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif)

Comment: using [score + 5] instead of [++score] returns a value of 0. (it doesn't work)

Comment: @Juhana How would jQuery help with adding 5 to a variable?

Comment: @LeeTaylor It was clearly a joke. And a bad one considering the OP is new to programming and likely has never even heard of JQuery.

Comment: Try with this: score += 5;

Comment: @keypaul Thank you! That's the easiest solution posted (least amount of code). Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function add1() {
    alert("Adding +5 to your score!");
    score = score + 5;
    alert(score);

    };
```

Comment: We have a winner! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user3672496 This was already suggested 10 minutes ago by Rudiger Kidd. The only difference here is that he re-wrote that single line in your function.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice he edited his post, it used to say "score = 5;" which did not help me, but then he changed it.

Comment: @user3672496 It used to say `var score = score + 5;`, which was admittedly unhelpful because it shadowed your global variable `score` with a new one in local scope, which was lost when the function returned (making it look like it did nothing). However, that was a type, and was fixed. I believe you should accept his answer because that *single line* is the real 'answer' to the question - you wanted to know how to add 5 to a variable, and his answer does that. This answer makes it look like you needed a whole function to do it, and moreover was answered first by Rudiger Kidd :)

Answer (score 4):

shortest / easiest + 5 in Javascript

```
 score += 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

add + 5 to the score and set that as the score

```
 score = score + 5;
```

Comment: I need to be able to add to the variable rather than just assign the variable again (because this function would be used a lot and score goes beyond 5). But thanks for the input.

Comment: Using `var` there creates a local variable called `score` which shadows the global variable.

Comment: @Juhana whoops, missed that

Comment: @user3672496 The `++` operator in Javascript is a fancy way to say `var = var + 1`. So if you want to add `5` to your score variable, `score = score + 5;` is exactly what you want. Whoever downvoted this, undo your downvote - the global variable shadow was edited out.

Comment: @user3672496 this does add, this is the same as saying newscore = oldscore + somenumber

Comment: @RudigerKidd Thank you, I understand now (sorry, I'm very new to this).

Comment: @user3672496 Code Academy is fine for learning programming, but it would be *very* beneficial to you to read [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254572/what-is-the-proper-way-to-approach-so-as-someone-totally-new-to-programming) so you can get a general idea of how to approach Stack Overflow. It is suggested that you do a bit of personal research before posting a question, because you often find that your question has already been answered, or can be [found on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=adding+numbers+in+javascript).

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in.It's like the web storage Api if you disable the alert.[Learn more](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

```js
var score = 0;
document.getElementById("boy").innerHTML = +score;

function correct() {
alert("And that is correct!")
++score;
document.getElementById("boy").innerHTML = +score;

return true;
}

function wrong() {
alert("And that is wrong!")

return false;
}


var times = 0;
document.getElementById("hey").innerHTML = +score;

function yourname() {
++times;
document.getElementById("hey").innerHTML = +times;

}
```

```html
<p>
Score:<span id="boy"></span>
</p>

<h2>Is javascript powerful?</h2>

<button onclick='correct()'>Yes</button>
<button onclick='wrong()'>No</button>

<h2>If you went into the w3schools link.This feels familar.</h2>

<p>
You have clicked the button:<span id="hey"></span> times
</p>

<button onclick="yourname()">Click me!!!</button>
```

You maybe will not see the snippet.

Javascript:

```
 var score = 0;
document.getElementById("boy").innerHTML = +score;

function correct() {
alert("And that is correct!")
++score;
document.getElementById("boy").innerHTML = +score;

return true;
}

function wrong() {
alert("And that is wrong!")

return false;
}


var times = 0;
document.getElementById("hey").innerHTML = +score;

function yourname() {
++times;
document.getElementById("hey").innerHTML = +times;

}
```

Html:

```
<p>
Score:<span id="boy"></span>
</p>

<h2>Is javascript powerful?</h2>

<button onclick='correct()'>Yes</button>
<button onclick='wrong()'>No</button>

<h2>If you went into the w3schools link.This feels familar.</h2>

<p>
You have clicked the button:<span id="hey"></span> times
</p>

<button onclick="yourname()">Click me!!!</button>
```